# How can share a WriteableBitmap back buffer to use alongside Direct2D rendering?

Tags: c#, direct2d, sharpdx, wic

I'm using a WriteableBitmap as a fast way to render and display content in a WPF window and than later export as media (reusing the same rendering pipeline).

I can draw images, basic shapes, do common operations manipulating the image bytes (resize, crop, flip, change angle, opacity, etc). Unrelated to this issue.

My rendering pipeline simply gets the WriteableBitmap back buffer (nint/IntPtr) and some of its parameters (size, scale, offset, etc.) and uses SharpDX to draw text like so:

```
public override void RenderAt(nint canvas, int canvasStride, int canvasWidth, int canvasHeight, 
    double horizontalScale, double verticalScale, int leftOffset, int topOffset, 
    int rightOffset, int bottomOffset) 
{
    using (var factory = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.Factory(FactoryType.MultiThreaded))
    using (var writeFactory = new SharpDX.DirectWrite.Factory(SharpDX.DirectWrite.FactoryType.Shared))
    using (var textFormat = new TextFormat(writeFactory, "Segoe UI", 20))
    using (var bitmap = new SharpDX.WIC.Bitmap(new ImagingFactory(), canvasWidth, canvasHeight, SharpDX.WIC.PixelFormat.Format32bppPBGRA, SharpDX.WIC.BitmapCreateCacheOption.CacheOnLoad))
    using (var renderTarget = new WicRenderTarget(factory, bitmap, new RenderTargetProperties()))
    {
        //Create a SharpDX Bitmap as the backbuffer.
        var backBufferBitmap = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap(renderTarget, new Size2(canvasWidth, canvasHeight), new SharpDX.Direct2D1.BitmapProperties(renderTarget.PixelFormat));
        backBufferBitmap.CopyFromMemory(canvas, canvasStride);

        renderTarget.BeginDraw();
        renderTarget.Transform = Matrix3x2.Scaling((float)horizontalScale, (float)verticalScale) * Matrix3x2.Translation(leftOffset, topOffset);
        
        //Get the current canvas content, to draw the text later.
        renderTarget.DrawBitmap(backBufferBitmap, 1f, BitmapInterpolationMode.Linear);

        var text = "Example";

        //Backdrop of the text.
        using (var brush = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.SolidColorBrush(renderTarget, new RawColor4(0,0,0,1)))
            renderTarget.FillRectangle(new RawRectangleF(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight / 4), brush);

        //Text.
        using (var brush = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.SolidColorBrush(renderTarget, new RawColor4(1,1,1,1)))
            renderTarget.DrawText(text, textFormat, new RectangleF(0, 0, Width, Height), brush);

        renderTarget.EndDraw();

        //Copy back the rendered result.
        bitmap.CopyPixels(new RawBox(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight), canvasStride, new DataPointer(canvas, canvasStride * canvasHeight));
    }
}
```

I wonder if it's possible to directly draw into that back buffer without having to do so many copy operations, because right now I have to do two copies.

Comment: There is a `RenderControl` that could presumably be used to draw to directly. It is a winforms control, but that can be hosted in a WPF control. But SharpDX has not seen a release since 2018, are you sure you want to build you application on top of it? Basic image operations like you mention can easily be done directly in WPF, most could probably be done by just manipulating the render and/or layout transforms.

Comment: I have been doing basic image operations directly, by manipulating bytes manually. I had to use Direct2D because I wanted to added support for text rendering.

Comment: And I need an easy to read/write image access to use the content both to display and to export as image/video/animation.

Answer (score 1):

WPF's WriteableBitmap already wraps a [WIC Bitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-bitmapsources) undercovers, so performance of your code can be improved maybe more than you think but it's not exposed publicly unfortunately.

You can get to it with a code like this:

```
var writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(200, 200, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null); // create some writeable bitmap

// get its internal COM reference
// PropertyInfo can be cached
var prop = writeableBitmap.GetType().GetProperty("WicSourceHandle", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var handle = (SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid)prop.GetValue(writeableBitmap, null);

using (var bitmap = new SharpDX.WIC.Bitmap(handle.DangerousGetHandle())) // we're already walking on the dangerous edge anyway
{
    etc...
    // EndDraw does Lock+Unlock
}
```

Note 1: WPF is quite frozen now, so I don't think it's a big risk to use this internal structure but it's up to you obviously.

Note 2: working on a WIC bitmap is working on the CPU. If you want even better performance you can use a Direct2D bitmap which resides on the GPU and can take advantage of GPU power. Requires probably important changes.

Comment: Wow, that's cool. I'm going to try that. I'm new to WIC, what's the difference between getting the WriteableBitmap.BackBuffer handle vs gettings the WicSourceHandle?

Comment: For note 2: Yes, right now I'm using CPU to render and export. I wanted to do things manually to learn, and it was easier (and fast enough) to just work with a WriteableBitmap (two actually, for a double buffer) and do basic byte operations.

Comment: Right now I can render 3440x1440p multi-layered content at 60fps on my non OC'd i7 8700k. Next phase I want to switch to the GPU.

Comment: WriteableBitmap.BackBuffer is not a handle, it's a pointer to the bitmap's memory. WicSourceHandle is the COM reference (a pointer) to an IWICBitmap (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincodec/nn-wincodec-iwicbitmap) implementation itself. From an IWICBitmap, calling Lock (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincodec/nf-wincodec-iwicbitmap-lock) will get you an IWICBitmapLock COM reference. From there, GetDataPointer (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincodec/nf-wincodec-iwicbitmaplock-getdatapointer) will get you the back buffer.